# Request.UrlReferrer returning null with IE 8

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to access the URL in `Request.UrlReferrer`. It works fine in Firefox and returns me the correct value. But, when I try and access it when debugging from Internet Explorer, it returns null.

My code:

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    if (Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().IndexOf("AspxPage.aspx") > -1)
    {
        // ------
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You should not rely on the referer that is sent from the client because every user can choose to send a referer or not (or a wrong one for that matter). In Firefox you can change this behavior when you type in your addressbar `about:config` and change the `network.http.sendrefererheader` property to 0 for example.

Comment: @Philipp, +1 fair point. But, if the OP is working in a corporate environment (for example) with "locked down" machines, utilising the referrer header would be perfectly reasonable, **IIF** it's a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: @BJP did you get any soln? same issue i'm facing here...