# What can I use in Place of URL Referrer check to know where the request is coming from on my domain?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to implement a single signon kind of solution on my website. Let's say my website is www.myweb.com and I want to allow the users to use this site who only come from a site www.sourceweb.com.

I thought URL Referrer would do but in IE may comes null.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307527/request-urlreferrer-returning-null-with-ie-8)

Please suggest me some alternate solution.

Thanks,

Gaurav

Comment: URL Referer can be empty or even faked so that is not reliable. There is no way to reliably make sure that a user comes from a specific site. That would be a privacy concern if websites could determine where a user has been.

Comment: @Sani: Atleast if I get some other solution, then might be combining it with URL Referrer do. What say?

Comment: @Guarav: Do you have access to www.sourceweb.com so that you can modify the code there?

Comment: @Sani: Partially... actually I am in contact with their one developer. We have come to a solution that we will be using a post request from www.sourceweb.com to www.myweb.com where in the form fields, there would be some encrypted user_name coming along with the request. I will have to decrypt it and make the user loggedin. Still I wanted to put some more security. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to www.sourceweb.com and can modify the source then a possible solution would be:

1. Create a webservice on www.myweb.com.
2. Create a link on www.sourceweb.com
3. When the link is clicked call the webservice to retrieve a unique id.
4. Redirect the user to www.myweb.com and provide the unique id in the querystring.
5. On www.myweb.com confirm that the unique id is valid and remove it/mark it as used.

Comment: good one. A similar one I am already using, but yours suggested is more secure.

Comment: Remember to secure the webservice to only allow requests from www.sourceweb.com.

Comment: Don't you think it is same as Secure myweb to only allow requests from www.sourceweb.com?

Comment: @Guarav: No you can't configure www.myweb.com to only allow connections from www.sourceweb.com because the connection doesn't come from there (unless all users are sitting on the same network). It comes from the users computer and that could be anywhere. The webservice on the other hand should only be accessed from www.sourceweb.com. The users don't need access to the webservice.

Comment: and test mark the user as login if the unique id is validated
and remember to ensure on all requests that the user is logged in and if not redirect to some login functionality
and make sure that the service replying to the authenticity of the unique Id can't be spoofed
and...

Comment: @gaurav establish two way SSL

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to skin a cat, one way in your case would be to set a cookie on the 2nd site, using a pixel gif (1x1 pixel small picture) embedded on a page of the main site. The 2nd site then can later allow access only when the cookie is already set.

To make this secure, you have to add a token to the pixel gif URL, containing a timestamp and signed using a HMAC or something similar establishing a shared secret with the other site. Then you only set the cookie when the timestamp is recent (less than a minute ago) and properly signed.

Answer (score 0):

`URL_REFERER` is your best bet.

Keep in mind that like most HTTP headers, it is easy to forge and does not have to be provided.

Comment: that is the only reason why I am trying to implement some alternate solution, the solution using URL_REFERER will not be full proof.

Comment: @gaurav - It's the only standard header that gives this information. Unless you have access to and can change the code of `sourceweb.com` to provide some sort of authentication credentials to you to prove that it is the actual referrer..

Answer (score 0):

The very short answer. Don't implement this yourself.
Security solutions should not be implemented but bought. The only exception being if you actually develops security solutions for other to buy of course.

Choose one of many available SSO solutions and go with that. We use Microsofts ADFS, though not perfect it gets the job done for us with very little maintance and the only real hazle is for our applications hosted on non-windows platforms like AIX.

There so many chance of screwing things up when you try to implement your own security solutions. If you disagree than just remember than anual contests are held to break the security systems of companies such as Apple,Microsoft,Mozilla and Goggle and most of the years some one takes home the price for breaking each of them.